# what do the lines ```predictions[a > 0.5] = 1``` and ```acc = np.mean(predictions == y)``` mean?

Tags: deep-learning

I am new to python programming. I am working on deep learning algorithms . I have never seen these type of lines in c or c++ programs.
**what do the lines `predictions[a > 0.5] = 1` and `acc = np.mean(predictions == y)` mean?**

```
def predict(x, w, b):
    a = sigmoid( w.T @ x + b)
    predictions =  np.zeros_like(a) 
    predictions[a > 0.5] = 1
    return predictions

def test_model(x, y, w, b):
    predictions = predict(x, w, b)
    acc = np.mean(predictions == y)
    acc = np.asscalar(acc)
    return acc

def main():
    x, y = load_train_data()
    x = flatten(x)
    x = x/255. # normalize the data to [0, 1]

    print(f'train accuracy: {test_model(x, y, w, b) * 100:.2f}%')

    x, y = load_test_data()
    x = flatten(x)
    x = x/255. # normalize the data to [0, 1]

    print(f'test accuracy: {test_model(x, y, w, b) * 100:.2f}%')
```

Thank You

Comment: Search for  `numpy` tutorials and spend some time there. It will help you to understand the above code

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, without knowing more, it is impossible to say, because `[]` is just invoking a method, which can be defined on any class:

```
class Indexable:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index:
            return "Truly indexed!"
        else:
            return "Falsely indexed!"

predictions = Indexable()
a = 0.7
predictions[a > 0.5]
# => 'Truly indexed!'
```

The same is true of the operator `>`.

---

However, from context, it is likely that both `predictions` and `a` are numpy arrays of same size, and `a` contains numbers.

`a > .5` will produce another array of the same size as `a` with `False` where the element is `.5` or smaller, and `True` where it is larger than `.5`.

`predictions[b]` where `b` is a boolean array of the same size will produce an array that only contains the elements where `b` is True:

```
predictions = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = [True, False, False, False, True]
predictions[b]
# => array([1, 5])
```

The indexed assignments are similar, setting a value only where the corresponding element in the index array is `True`:

```
predictions[b] = 17
predictions
# => array([17, 2, 3, 4, 17])
```

So the line you are wondering about is setting all the `predictions` where the corresponding `a` is over `0.5` to `1`.

---

As for the other line you're wondering about, the logic of `==` is similar to that of `>` above: `predictions == y` will give a boolean array telling where `predictions` and `y` coincide.

This array is then passed to `np.mean`, which calculates an arithmetic average of its argument. How do you get an average of `[True, False, False, False, True]` though? By coercing them to floats! `float(True)` is `1.0`; `float(False)` is `0.0`. The average of a boolean list thus basically tells you the fraction of elements that are true: `np.mean([True, False, False, True])` is the same as `np.mean([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])`, giving the result of `0.4` (or 40% of elements being `True`).

So your line calculates which proportion of `predictions` is same as `y` (in other words, accuracy of the prediction, assuming `y` is the gold data).